# How to download aes encrypted m3u8 using ffmpeg or youtube-dl?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, encryption, youtube-dl, hls

I have the m3u8 file and the key.bin, inside the m3u8 file is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="key.bin"
#EXTINF:6.000000,
segment-0.ts
...
#EXTINF:4.416667,
segment-159.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

and inside the key.bin file is

```
Ú{±€rl”ÜJÌy«‡mó
```

How do I download this as an mp4 using ffmpeg or youtube-dl?.

Comment: You can [share the knowledge](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) then.

Comment: youtube-dl -o file.mp4 "m3u8-URL"

might need to pass proper headers for youtube-dl/ffmpeg to be allowed to download the key. use --user-agent "" and --referer "" (use same user-agent as your browser, find yours easily at ifconfig.me/ua, and referer is the main URL in the browser from where you sniffed out the m3u8 URL) ( Thanks goes to the guy from reddit who gave the solution.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use ffmpeg like so:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i video.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc video.mp4
```

Also if the urls are https you can add https to allowed protocols like so:

```bsh
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i video.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc video.mp4
```

Original article:
[Download encrypted HLS content with ffmpeg - davd.io](https://www.davd.io/download-encrypted-hls-content-with-ffmpeg/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `youtube-dl -o file.mp4 "m3u8-URL"`, you might need to might need to pass proper headers for youtube-dl/ffmpeg to be allowed to download the key. use the `--user-agent "USERAGENT"` and `--referer "REFERRER_URL"` argument. You need to use same user-agent as your browser-you can find yours easily at [ifconfig.me/ua,](https://ifconfig.me/ua) and referer is the main URL in the browser from where you sniffed out the m3u8 URL)

E.g:

```
ua='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0'
ref='Referer: https://play.example.com/'
m3u8='https://audio.api.streaming.example.com/hls/bu627ad3-b805-4n6d-9dc9-495fd113d47f/playlist.m3u8'

youtube-dl -o file.mp4 --user-agent "$ua" --referer "$ref" "$m3u8"
```

Credit goes to the guy from reddit who gave the solution.

Comment: -1 because the answer is basically unreadable

Comment: Set "referer" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a field such as `EXT-X-KEY`, the `URI` value first needs to be
resolved, relative to the playlist URI. So if you have this:

```
http://example.com/hello/playlist.m3u8
```

then the resultant URI will be:

```
http://example.com/hello/key.bin
```

once thats done, you can get the data from the URI, typically 16 bytes or more.
You can then resolve a segment URI:

```
http://example.com/hello/segment-0.ts
```

and download as normal. Next you can decrypt the segment using AES-CBC, using
the data from `key.bin`, as both the AES key, and the CBC IV. After decrypting,
you'll need to remove any padding, if it exists. Repeat this process for all
the segments.

[RFC 8216 - EXT-X-KEY](//datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.4)